# How to change formats of date from a datasoucre which has multiple formats in quicksight?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am trying to create an analysis in quicksight using a function of time.

But the problem is, the field which I am using has date in string format as follows:
Most of the rows have this format: ["2018-11-30T19:39:14+00:00"]
and few of the rows have this format: 2022-08-18 20:54:18

I have to convert them all so that I can represent them as a function of time aggregated by month.

I tried using parse method but it returns most of the rows as null

Answer (score 1):

This article lists date formats supported depending on the backend.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/parseDate-function.html

I believe +00:00 at the end specifies time zone and there are no formats with timezone listed for the parseDate function.

If I were you, I would first define intermediate calculated field that operates on the string to replace letter 'T' in the middle with space and removes +00:00 (If the numbers after + can be non-zero, calculation becomes more complex since you need to adjust time zone).

After replacing 'T' and removing everything after +, you should be able to use parseDate function to convert all strings to the date data type.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. I used substring function to extract 3rd to 12th letter of the string. So for most of the rows, I have correct date in string such as 2022-09-13, but for few of the rows which were in format '2022-08-18 20:54:18'
are now showing up as '22-08-18 2'